# R - Sum range over lookback period, divided sum of look back - excel to R

Tags: r

I am looking to workout a percentage total over a look back range in R.

I know how to do this in excel with the following formula:

```
=SUM(B2:B4)/SUM(B2:B4,C2:C4)
```

This is summing column B over a range of today looking back 3 lines. It then divides this sum buy the total sum of column B + C again looking back 3 lines.

I am looking to achieve the same calculation in R to run across my matrix.

The output would look something like this:

```
    adv dec perct
1   69  376 
2   113 293 
3   270 150 0.355625492
4   74  371 0.359559402
5   308 96  0.513790386
6   236 173 0.491255962
7   252 134 0.663886572
8   287 129 0.639966969
9   219 187 0.627483444
```

This is a line of code I could perhaps add the look back range too:

```
perct <- apply(data.matrix[,c('adv','dec')], 1, function(x) { (x[1] / x[1] + x[2]) } )
```

If i could get [1] to sum the previous 3 line range and
If i could get [2] to also sum the previous 3 line range.

Still learning how to apply forward and look back periods within R. So any additional learning on the answer would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some approaches. The first 3 use `rollsumr` and/or `rollapplyr` in zoo and the last one uses only the base of R.

**1) rollsumr** Create a matrix with `rollsumr` whose columns contain the rollling sums, convert that to row proportions and take the `"adv"` column. Finally assign that to a new column `frac` in `DF`.  This approach has the shortest code.

```
library(zoo)

DF$frac <- prop.table(rollsumr(DF, 3, fill = NA), 1)[, "adv"]
```

giving:

```
> DF
  adv dec      frac
1  69 376        NA
2 113 293        NA
3 270 150 0.3556255
4  74 371 0.3595594
5 308  96 0.5137904
6 236 173 0.4912560
7 252 134 0.6638866
8 287 129 0.6399670
9 219 187 0.6274834
```

**1a)** This variation is similar except instead of using `prop.table` we write out the ratio.  The code is longer but you may find it clearer.

```
m <- rollsumr(DF, 3, fill = NA)
DF$frac <- with(as.data.frame(m), adv / (adv + dec))
```

**1b)** This is a variation of (1) that is the same except it uses a magrittr pipeline:

```
library(magrittr)

DF %>% rollsumr(3, fill = NA) %>% prop.table(1) %>% `[`(TRUE, "adv") -> DF$frac
```

**2) rollapplyr**  We could use `rollapplyr` with `by.column = FALSE` like this.  The result is the same.

```
ratio <- function(x) sum(x[, "adv"]) / sum(x)
DF$frac <- rollapplyr(DF, 3, ratio, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)
```

**3)**  Yet another variation is to compute the numerator and denominator separately:

```
DF$frac <- rollsumr(DF$adv, 3, fill = NA) / 
    rollapplyr(DF, 3, sum, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)
```

**4) base** This uses `embed` followed by `rowSums` on each column to get the rolling sums and then uses `prop.table` as in (1).

```
DF$frac <- prop.table(sapply(lapply(rbind(NA, NA, DF), embed, 3), rowSums), 1)[, "adv"]
```

**Note:** The input used in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "adv dec 
1   69  376 
2   113 293 
3   270 150
4   74  371
5   308 96 
6   236 173
7   252 134
8   287 129
9   219 187"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is a nice way to do it within the zoo package! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Consider an `sapply` that loops through the number of rows in order to index two rows back:

```
DF$pred <- sapply(seq(nrow(DF)), function(i)
  ifelse(i>=3, sum(DF$adv[(i-2):i])/(sum(DF$adv[(i-2):i]) + sum(DF$dec[(i-2):i])), NA))

DF
#   adv dec      pred
# 1  69 376        NA
# 2 113 293        NA
# 3 270 150 0.3556255
# 4  74 371 0.3595594
# 5 308  96 0.5137904
# 6 236 173 0.4912560
# 7 252 134 0.6638866
# 8 287 129 0.6399670
# 9 219 187 0.6274834
```

Comment: Thank you - this is nice to see how it works in a loop